# Laravel: Appending plain XML at the end of email

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm using the following code in my Mailable build function to append some XML to the end of my outgoing email

```
        return $this->view('emails.adf-lead', [
            'lead' => $lead,
            'preview_text' => $previewText,
        ])
        ->to($adfEmail)
        ->subject($subject)
        ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($adfXML) {
            $body = $message->getBody();
            $message->setBody($body . "\n\n" . $adfXML);
        });
```

I can confirm `$adfXML` contains the right XML and is not empty.

The email goes out, but when I inspect the source, the XML is not there. What am I doing wrong?